# Scala data structure to deduplicate work done by akka

Tags: scala, data-structures, duplicates, akka, etl

I would like to implement a data structure in scala that would allow me to deduplicate work being done by my program. The program is built on akka-scala framework.

Every time I receive a message in my worker, I would check this data structure for what is currently being processed. If such message type is already in process, I would just store it in that data structure and wait for processed result. When processed result arrives, I would send acks for all stored messages of this type, and remove it from the structure

If such message type is not found in this data structure, I would store it there and start processing.

So far I think of something like `mutable.Map[Long, Seq[ETLMessageMeta]]`

Is there anything better for such a task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If each unit of work is uniquely identifiable, then a `Map` sounds like a good fit. However, instead of using a `mutable.Map`, use an `immutable.Map` that is a `var`, in order to help ensure that this mutable state is not leaked outside of the worker actor. For example:

```
class Worker extends Actor {
  var inProgress = immutable.Map[Long, Seq[ETLMessageMeta]]()

  def receive = ???
}
```